# AWS S3 read access to IAM user from external IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, acl

I want to allow a specific IAM user (and no one else) to read files from a specific S3 bucket. I want to allow this IAM user to read the files from any external IP address. I have already created this IAM user, and attached a custom policy to this user allowing `s3:GetObject` operations on the one bucket.

I have also configured my S3 bucket to "Block all public access." My reasoning is that I don't want to allow access from any other user/stranger besides the designated IAM user.

I attempted to perform the read using the S3 SDK and the IAM user's API keys. And I'm getting the following error: `Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied`

I suspect that this is happening because of my "block all public access" bucket config. I don't quite understand what AWS is referring to when they say `public`. Are they referring to access from random/uncredentialed users? Or are they referring to access from public IP addresses? For my use case, should I enable or disable the following configs?

- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)
- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)
- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies
- Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies

---

**Update**: Turns out I made an unrelated error in my permissions policy. I had granted the IAM user permissions to access `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket` instead of `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*`.

After fixing this, I'm able to use the IAM user to read from the s3 bucket, from an external IP, with `block all public access` still enabled. I can now confirm that this option does not block access from external IPs.

Thank you Mark B!

Comment: Blocking public access does not also block IAM users. I suggest adding the user's IAM policy, and your code to your question. Have you added a bucket policy to the S3 bucket? If so include that in your question as well.

Comment: `block all public access` actually means "block all unauthenticated access"

Comment: Thank you @MarkB for the tip that blocking public access won't block IAM users from external IP addresses. While retrieving the IAM policy, I realized my mistake and have successfully fixed it. I have updated the post with more details